# How do I reduce the tarball size of an R package?

Tags: r, bioconductor

In Bioconductor, it is required that the tarball size should be <= 4MB but my package's tarball size is 50MB.  I checked the folders and found that the actual package is less than 1MB but the .git folder is taking all the spaces. Why is the size of the package's tarball high?

Comment: How exactly are you building your package? The .git folder shouldn't be included in the tarball.

Comment: The package did not include the .git folder but the size is still 50MB

Comment: Well, you've given us very little info to work with here. Just take a look at the file sizes in the tarball to see what's taking up the space: https://superuser.com/questions/51920/show-tar-files-sizes

Comment: @MrFlick This is my package link https://github.com/mshasan/OPWeight. I figured out the problem but I do not know how to stop this during cMD check. During the R cmd check, it always generates the OPWeight_cache folders. I basically need to stop geenrating OPWeight_files/,
OPWeight_cache/,
OPWeight.html, and
OPWeight.R